# How to set background color according to x-axis partition values in chart with MPAndroidChart library by PhilJay?

Tags: android, linechart

I would like to set background color according to x-axis partition values in chart using together with line chart. Is there any way to set like this picture in android with MPAndroid Chart?

[Line Chart with MPAndroid Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4e0O.png)

Comment: If you look at this thread(https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3406) There is code for changing color according to Y-axis. With some modification, you might be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set bar data then use this one.

```
  val barDataSet = BarDataSet(mListOfBarEntry, "Colors")
  barDataSet.color = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
```

In this i have changed the background color of bar.

Comment: Thank you! I will try with this way.